# Why can't Chrome 83 play this AV1 encoded video?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, html5-video, playback

The file plays great in VLC.

I've tried adding the `codecs="av01.0.05M.08"` to the video source, but no luck - no browser will play it, despite what's stated here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=av1

**The video was encoded like so:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -pix_fmt yuva420p -f nut -c:v libaom-av1 -minrate 1k -b:v 350k -maxrate 2000k -strict experimental output.mp4
```

**Browser console:**

- Chrome gives no hint whatsoever as to why it won't play. Firefox gives some minor clues.
- Firefox shows the below

```
Media resource https://example.com/example.mp4 could not be decoded. example.mp4
```

```
Media resource https://example.com/example.mp4 could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)
Details: static MP4Metadata::ResultAndByteBuffer __cdecl mozilla::MP4Metadata::Metadata(mozilla::ByteStream *): Cannot parse metadata
```

Any advice on where I'm going wrong, either in understanding or in encoding arguments, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manually selected the NUT muxer with `-f nut` but gave the output file name `.mp4`, so it is actually NUT format which isn't supported by browsers. Try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libaom-av1 -minrate 1k -b:v 350k -maxrate 2000k -vf format=yuv420p -strict experimental -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Note that libaom-av1 does not support `yuva420p` pixel format so `yuv420p` was used instead. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libaom-av1`.